# How to define Global Variable in Node/Express after Post/Get Request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to define Global Variable in Node/Express file after Post/Get Request?
For payment system need to define payment id, which is received after POST request. so I need to get
current payment id and pass to next get request dynamically. Everything works well instead of pass dynamically payment Id. How can I do this?

Example code from my project:

```
let paymentId;
```

```
app.post("/api/payments", (req, res) => {
  var { body } = req;
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    amount: {
      currency: "GEL",
      total: body.amount,
      subTotal: 0,
      tax: 0,
      shipping: 0,
    },
    returnurl: "http://localhost:3000/success",
    userIpAddress: "127.0.0.1",
    expirationMinutes: "5",
    methods: [5, 7, 8],
    callbackUrl: "url",
    preAuth: true,
    language: "EN",
    merchantPaymentId: "P123123",
    saveCard: false,
  });
 axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.tbcbank.ge/v1/tpay/payments",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      apikey: apiKey,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    data,
  })
.then(function (response) {
      res.json(response.data);
      paymentId = response.data.paymentId
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

// get payment info

```
app.get("/api/payments", (req, res) => {
  var config = {
    method: "get",
    url: `https://api.tbcbank.ge/v1/tpay/payments//${paymentId}`,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      apikey: apiKey,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      res.json(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I would suggest returning the ID to the frontend (or whatever is making the call), and the frontend should pass it in its call to the GET handler. Perhaps via a query parameter or a route parameter. If you store it in a global, how will you know it's the same client as the one making the POST call? In that case, you could perhaps store it in the user's [session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), but when would it be cleared?

Comment: You **don't** define global variables from client requests. Your server will have multiple clients, your server will handle multiple requests at the same time. You want either a session variable, or a persistence solution such as a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty object and assign new properties or delete/re-assign existing properties. This is an example implementation:

```
const memory = {};

app.post('/api/payments', (req, res) => {
  const randomId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
  memory.paymentId = randomId;
  res.send(`Created random paymentId: ${paymentId}`);
});

app.get('/api/payments', (req, res) => {
  res.json({paymentid: memory.paymentId});
});
```

[image: POST method]
[image: GET method]